# Android Dialog and Intents

Tags: android, view, android-activity, dialog, android-intent

I would like to create something similiar to Java's JFileChooser to use in my program.  Specifically, I want a user to click a View and have a dialog appear.  Once open, the user selects a file and I want to know which file they selected.

I have two `Activity` classes.  One class has a lot of code, and I would really like to separate the other class to only obtain files the user selected.

These Activities are called `MeActivity` and `FileDialog`.  I have to create an Intent in `MeActivity` to ultimately get the chosen file from `FileDialog`.

In `MeActivity`, currenty I have something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,FileDialog.class);      
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

But how do I get the dialog to work with the view listener?  When a view is pressed, I want it to trigger the dialog.

I am trying to use `AlertDialog.Builder` to create the dialog that `FileDialog` will show to the user.  I have placed it in `"onCreateDialog(int id)"`

In `MeActivity`, do I need to call `"onActivityResult(...)"` explicity to get the file that the user selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can display the dialog on any view click event by calling `showDialog(0);` method.

### Example

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            showDialog(0);

            }

    });
```

Comment: In MeActivity do I set "showDialog()" (and remember FileDialog is another class that is supposed to handle the dialog - show to user and get file)?

Comment: I did more reading and it seems a call to "showDialog()" will use "onCreateDialog(...)" in the respective Activity to determine which exact dialog is to be shown.  So, this means I must use "showDialog()" in the FileDialog Activity for my project, is that right?